# Instanceof equivalent for Object.create and prototype chains

Tags: javascript, instanceof, object-create

Consider such an object with a prototype chain:

```
var A = {};
var B = Object.create(A);
var C = Object.create(B);
```

How to check in runtime if C has A in its prototype chain?

`instanceof` doesn't fit as it's designed to work with constructor functions, which I'm not using here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My answer will be short…

You could use the `isPrototypeOf` method, which will be present in case your object inherits from the Object prototype, like your example.

example:

```
A.isPrototypeOf(C) // true
B.isPrototypeOf(C) // true
Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(C) // false
```

More info can be read here: [Mozilla Developer Network: isPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/IsPrototypeOf)

Comment: +1 Simple solution. Although your examples are completely correct, it would be `Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(C)` to check whether `C` is an array (I found your last example a little bit ambiguous - using `isPrototypeOf` on a function is usually not what you want).

Comment: You're absolutely right, i didn't want to lose too much time since an answer was already given at the time, so i didn't think too much on the examples, my objective was only to show the method available... still i will correct the example given with your answer, since as you said and i agree, my last example is ambiguous, thanks for the notice =)

Comment: Just a quick question: how is it possible for object not to inherit from Object? Any object has a [[Prototype]] reference that through chain of prototypes eventually leads to Object.prototype.

Comment: @ViktorStolbin You can use `var a = Object.create(null);` To get an object with null as prototype.

Answer (score 4):

You could iterate back through the prototype chain by calling `Object.getPrototypeOf` recursively: http://jsfiddle.net/Xdze8/.

```
function isInPrototypeChain(topMost, itemToSearchFor) {
    var p = topMost;

    do {

        if(p === itemToSearchFor) {
            return true;
        }

        p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p); // prototype of current

    } while(p); // while not null (after last chain)

    return false; // only get here if the `if` clause was never passed, so not found in chain
}
```

Comment: +1 Was about to post a near *identical* answer, even with the `do-while`, which I don't see too often. But yours is made into a function, which is nicer.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Funny, I was also thinking about the fact that I was using the `do` keyword which I almost never do.

Comment: I'm surprised that there isn't an `Object.hasPrototype` proposal for ES6 that does exactly what your function does. It just seems a natural complement `Object.create` as `instanceof` is to `new Constructor`. It could even accept a function as the second argument, which would use the function's `prototype` as the target.

Comment: Can you confirm that recent EcmaScript didn't add a built-in feature for that? I have a memory that this existed, but might be just my imagination :-)

Comment: @Kos: I don't know which function that should be. None of the functions listed at MDN seem to implement this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods.